# DataGrip: script to export multiple queries to CSV needed

Tags: datagrip

I would like to export 5 queries from 5 different databases to 5 local csv files. Best by only starting one script doing this.

In the old days in MS Access I used multiple "DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet" for this in one VB script. Is there something similar in DataGrip?

```
use db1;
exportToCsv1(select * from...);
use db2;
exportToCsv2(select * from...);
...
```

Comment: We are wirking on the ability to make it at once

Answer (score 1):

In DataGrip, to export query result to CSV please use **Execute to File** from the context menu.
[image]

The alternative way is to export the result itself.

[image]